# Understand openDeclarartion functionality (f3). How can I debug the openDeclaration in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, eclipse-plugin

I'm trying to add the `openDeclaration` function to my own Eclipse plugin editor. Until now I didn't really understand how the f3 functionality works (I read something about Hyperlinking, `openAction`, and `compilationUnit.findDeclaringNode()`), but i cannot put the pieces together and understand how it work.

Until now i thought it works like this: 
While parsing the code, the tokens which are read will be added to the ast. The hierarchy level is `IJavaProject/IPackageFragmentRoot/IPackageFragment/ICompilationUnit/{IType / IField / IMethod}` With jdt it is possible to work with this ast. Each Java file is represented with a compilation unit. If I press f3, a `ActionHandler` is started which takes the `IjavaElement` that I hover in this moment.

Right now I have the `IJavaElement` in my Editor Plugin but I don't know how to jump to the corresponding type/method associated with the declaration in the compilation unit. 
And I don't know what will happen if the declaring node is not in the same compilation unit, like if it's a basic type (Such as a String or an Integer).

Maybe if everything if was more clear, I could follow the way how the default Java editor is doing this task. 
How do I get the pieces together or how can I debug the functionality?

Comment: You can read the source of `org.eclipse.jdt.ui.actions.OpenAction` which implements Open Declaration.

Comment: Thank you, it helped me to get further. Do you know any sources/litertur where i can read more abot everything is working together?

Comment: @greg-449 I see that OpenAction, and SelectionDispatchAction are described as "not intended to be subclassed by clients". What class should be subclassed (or what interface implemented) in order to implement F3 functionality in a non-Java plugin?

Comment: @Eyal Actions are now deprecated. Use Commands, Handlers and Key bindings for new code

Comment: @greg-449 Yes, I read that in the documentation, but I haven't found yet which command represents F3. Do you know a plugin that has a command for F3 I can look at as an example? I know the JDT isn't supposed to be representative

Comment: For future reference - the command I ended up overriding is _org.eclipse.jdt.ui.edit.text.java.open.editor_.